# Where can I override jwt_response_payload_handler method?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have installed the JWT with pip. Now I want to override the method

```
def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
    return { 'token': token, }
```

to be

```
def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None):
    return {
        'token': token,
        'user': UserSerializer(user).data
    }
```

Where should I override it? Do I override the method in my own app, but where and how? or do I modify the original code in the library?

I have modified the method in the library and it works fine, but I don't think it is correct way to do. Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Once you create your own handler method you'll have to change it in the JWT_AUTH setting. Check out the [Additional Settings](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#additional-settings) section in the docs.

Comment: The thing is where I should create the own handler method? in my own app or in the JWT library? I can modify the library and then it works. The thing I am not sure is should I do it, modify the file in the library?

Comment: @song The handler method goes anywhere available to your sys.path, usually anywhere inside your project is fine, example: 'my_project.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler'

Comment: What if you want to edit the settings on a per app basis?  For example.  I have an internal facing API that I don't want to use refresh tokens for, so my settings are: `JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(hours=12),
}`.  But I also have a consumer facing api, that I want the settings to be `JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=300),
    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(hours=12)
}`.  How would I have the views recognize the different settings in each app.

Answer (score 28):

I found success doing the following:

myapp.view.py file:

```
def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
    return {
        'token': token,
        'bunny': 'fu fu'
    }
```

setting.py file:

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    #'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',
    'myapp.views.jwt_response_payload_handler',
}
```

Implementing the function `jwt_response_payload_handler` in an arbitrary location, but make sure it is in your python path. For example in this file: myapp.views.py

Then in your settings.py file update the `JWT_AUTH` dictionary key `JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER` with the new location of the `jwt_response_payload_handler` you just created.

Once you grasp what's going on, you can adapt the solution how you would like. For example, I would not recommend leaving your overridden function in the views.py file. It was just simpler for demonstrating purposes.

Perhaps placing the `jwt_response_payload_handler` function in a "helper.py" file you create would be a simple solution.

Comment: This helped me very much. It was simple and written in the documentation clearly and yet i failed to understand there. Thank you.

Comment: An update for anyone who runs into this issue in 2018. You must have 'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler', also in JWT_AUTH or the override will not work.

Comment: @JohnZ Thanks for the update John. If you create an edit and I'll approve it.

Comment: it still doesn't work with me. Using Django 2 not sure if it matters at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER
payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
```